# How to get default value of an enum from a type variable

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, default

Given an object (unknown at design time), I loop on its properties to do some processes. On each property, I have to check whether its value is different from the default value or not.

```
foreach(var p in propertyInfos)
{
    if (something) { ... }
    else if (p.PropertyType.IsEnum)
    {
        object oDefault = GetDefaultValueOfThisPropertyByWhateverMethod();
        if (oDefault == null)
            oDefault = default(p.PropertyType); // not valid
        var vValue = p.GetValue(myObject);

        if (!oDefault.Equals(vValue))
            // Do something enum specific when value is not the default one.
    }
}
```

How could I achieve this, knowing that there may exist enums that do not containt items with value 0?

Comment: The default value of any `enum` is value zero, it doesn't matter if the `enum` contains an item with that value or not.

Comment: @DavidG But note that it is a "typed" zero...

Comment: @pijemcolu But that is invalid code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default value of an `enum` is 0... Even if there is no value defined for 0. In the end you can always `(EnumType)123` for any `enum`. `enum` don't check/restrict their "valid" values. Only give some labels to some specific values.

Note that the 0 I spoke before is a "typed" value... So it is `(EnumType)0`, not a `(int)0`... You can:

```
object oDefault = Enum.ToObject(p.PropertyType, 0);
```

Works even with non-`int` based enums, like:

```
enum MyEnum : long
{
}
```

Clearly you could even:

```
object oDefault = Activator.CreateInstance(p.PropertyType);
```

because `new SomeEnumType()` is 0.

Comment: Thanks xanatos, this works like a charm! I used your first hint with `Enum.ToObject` and now my code works as expected.